# Android TextInputLayout crashes when setting error text dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-launcher, android-textinputlayout

The below is the code in which I created TextInputLAyout dynamically and EditText added to it dynamically.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);
textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
textInputLayout.setError("You need to enter a name");
textInputLayout.addView(textField);
```

The above code gives the below exception related to setBackGroundTintColor

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: according to logs setBackgroundTintList() is getting called some where, can you please post that code also.

Comment: in order to properly debug this issue, you need to provide more context for the code sample, a full stack trace, the version of android, and the version of the android support library.